# Can not execute a sys_refcursor function without parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I have this sys_refcursor function in a package

```
function frcBaanCompanies return SYS_REFCURSOR is
 x sys_refcursor;
begin
  open x for select t$comp, t$cpnm from baan.tttaad100000 order by t$comp;
  return x;
end;
```

and a net method calling this as so

```c#
listBox1.DataSource = lO.fRefCursor("priceWorx.frcBaanCompanies", null, false).Tables[0];
```

Here's how I call the function:

```c#
public DataSet fRefCursor(String refCursorName, IDictionary<string, string> prms, bool leaveConnectionOpen = true)
{
    try
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = refCursorName;
            if (prms!=null) SetupParams(refCursorName, cmd, prms);
            using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                }
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!leaveConnectionOpen) conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The same method works fine when called with parameters(some other cursor function, but fails with

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'FRCBAANCOMPANIES' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

works fine when executed within (Oracle) sql developer too..

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: When you say that this method 'works fine when called with parameters', could you provide an example of a function that takes parameters and how you would call it using your `fRefCursor` method above?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't call a function without parameters, but you could call it with null parameters. What you are currently calling when you do not input any parameters is:

```
FRCBAANCOMPANIES;
```

and this is different to

```
variable := FRCBAANCOMPANIES;
```

In the first case oracle is looking for a procedure without any return and in the second case you call your function. So you have to set the return parameter also if you do not need it.